# how to track which users are making what JMX calls via logs for hawtio in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jmx, hawtio, jolokia

How can I track what user is making what JMX calls via the hawtio web UI? I am running hawtio on tomcat. I am stuck at seeing any meaningful event logs at all.

I am able to log in with user scott/tiger but logs stop generating after login. The last logs I see are:

```
26-Jul-2023 18:42:14.482 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [4899] milliseconds
18:42:14 INFO {http-nio-8090-exec-5} : Hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
18:42:15 INFO {http-nio-8090-exec-7} : Keycloak integration is disabled
18:42:18 INFO {http-nio-8090-exec-9} : Logging in user: null
```